# como resolvo erros de acentuação ao enviar uma mensagem do Android para uma API em php

Tags: java, android, string, mobile

Gente, estou com problemas para realizar o envio de strings com acentuação e de strings com 2 linhas ou mais . Quando envio sem acentuação ou e com apenas uma linha ele aceita normalmente, porem, quando envio com acentuação, ele da erro.

Já utilizei um testador de API (Rest Easy), e quando envio por lá, ele aceita normalmente e não apresenta nenhum erro, mas quando envio pelo Android, da erro...

este é o trecho do código relacionado ao envio..

```
public void enviaDados() {
    new LongOperation().execute("");
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String msg = mensagem.getText().toString();
    String mail = email.toString();

    ProgressBar carrega = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.carregaMsg);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Log.v("GG", "Sending sever 1 - try");
            // start - line is for sever connection/communication
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.meuSite.com.br/mural/listener.php");

            String json = "{\"usuario\":[{\"enviado\":\"" + "1" + "\",\"email\":\"" + mail.toString() + "\",\"msg\":\"" + msg.toString() + "\",\"a\":\"" + "2" + "\"}]}"; //msg.toString()

            StringEntity entity1 = new StringEntity(json);
            httppost.setEntity(entity1);
            //informa o tipo de arquivo. . .
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            // end - line is for sever connection/communication
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            //_______________________________________________________________________
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            result = sb.toString();
            is.close();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            //__________________________________________________________________________

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "
                    + e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        carrega.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        try {
            alerta();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mensagem.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        carrega.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Caso alguém saiba me ajudar, ficaria muito grato.
Toda dica é bem vinda, agradeço pela atenção!

abraço!

Comment: Está dando qual erro?

Comment: Qual enconding (charset) o server tá utilizando? O Rest Easy funciona, pois ele usa o mesmo charset configurado na aplicacao Rest que recebe os dados no servidor. Você precisa configurar o mesmo charset na sua aplicacao Android. Ser for UTF-8, tente fazer: httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou tentar aqui agora, caso consiga ou não, aviso vocês 

Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, tentei desta forma mas, infelizmente ele ainda não reconhece
quando coloco acentos ou mais de uma linha, ele apresenta o mesmo erro. Caso alguém tenha alguma outra ideia para solucionar esta questão, mande por favor.

Comment: Tche, consegui resolver aqui
utilizei sua dica, mas para ela funcionar, tive que alterar a linha  StringEntity entity1 = new StringEntity(json); 

Ela ficou desta forma:

StringEntity entity1 = new StringEntity(json, "utf-8");

isso resolveu os acentos
agora só me falta resolver a quebra de linha
por exemplo, digito uma mensagem, dou enter no telefone e sigo digitando na segunda linha

ele acaba quebrando o json em 2 linhas ao invés de reconhecer um \n por exemplo

agora só vou descobrir como resolver isso hehe

brigadão!

Comment: Resolvi quera de linha acrescentando android:singleLine="true" no Script XML do editi text 

Valew galera e obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score -4):

Tenta colocar o `\n` seguido da palavra da linha seguinte, sem espaços.

Exemplo:

```
"Olá!\nTudo bem?
```